# Webscraping no result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print the href of the sneakers on the website everysize.com
[Inspected website for href&class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vth0E.png)

The href is in a li class='item span3 reduced reduced--value loaded' and i tried to print it with this code

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = 'https://www.everysize.com/'

headers = {
'User-Agent' : 'my user agent which i deleted for this'
 }

r = requests.get('https://www.everysize.com/sneaker-sale/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

productlist = soup.find_all('li', class_='item span3 reduced reduced--value loaded')

productlinks = [] 

 for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

when i trie to run this code in the terminal i only get the message:
**[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.775 seconds**
but it should have printed the individual hrefs? Anyone can see what i did wrong

Comment: Using your code, changing your parser from `lxml` to `html.parser`, and changing the tag class to simply `item` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

To print all links from this site you can use this example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.everysize.com/sneaker-sale/"
baseurl = "https://www.everysize.com"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("a.item-link"):
    print(baseurl + a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.everysize.com/nike-air-force-1-cv1758-100.html
https://www.everysize.com/adidas-originals-ultraboost-20-eg0754.html
https://www.everysize.com/nike-air-force-1-pixel-ck6649-100.html
https://www.everysize.com/nike-air-force-1-07-ct2302-100.html
https://www.everysize.com/nike-air-force-1-07-dd8959-100.html
https://www.everysize.com/nike-air-force-1-gs-sneaker-314192-117.html
https://www.everysize.com/nike-air-max-270-sneaker-ah8050-100.html
https://www.everysize.com/nike-air-max-270-sneaker-ah8050-002.html
https://www.everysize.com/adidas-originals-supercourt-ee6037.html

...
```

Comment: TY this worked,but do you know how i can change my code to work as-well ? I assume it has to do something with the class and loop but i cant find the mistake

Comment: @Beypa Do `print(soup)` and observe, if `class="item span3 reduced reduced--value loaded"` is present. If not, change it accordingly.